# Amazon Hero widget retains information from previous application

Tags: android, widget, android-appwidget, amazon-fire-os

When developing a sample list Hero widget application on the Amazon Fire phone I noticed that if I uninstall the application and install it again, the content from the previous application widget is displayed in the newly installed application.

Is this an expected behavior of the widget, because I cannot find any information about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Amazon Fire phone just performed an update to a new operating system version(3.5.1) and after this update, the hero widget does not retain anymore information from the previous application.
It looks like this issue was fixed with the new system update.